# react-native-vector-icons causing issues with android build

Tags: android, react-native

I am having an extremely difficult time trying to get `react-native run-android` to work on my mac so that my react-native android project runs in an emulator.  The command runs fine on my windows machine.

This is the error I'm getting:

> > Configure project :react-native-vector-icons  The CompileOptions.bootClasspath property has been deprecated and is
> >     scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the
> >     CompileOptions.bootstrapClasspath property instead.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
>   >     A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-vector-icons'.
>   >     Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
>   >     com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir(Ljava/io/File;)V

In my Android Studio, I am using the Virtual Device `Pixel API 26, API = 26, Target = Android 8.0 (Google APIs)`.

Here are the SDK Platforms I've selected:

[image]
[image]

For the SDK Tools, I selected `23.0.1,26.0.1,26.0.2,27.0.1`.

How do I get `react-native run-android` to make the app show in my emulator?

Comment: Got currently the same. Did you succeed to managed it ?

Answer (score 0):

- Try commenting out all references to react-native-vector-icons and see if your project runs without
- Try getting a newer version of react-native-vector-icons
- Try running `react-native run-android --info --scan` and if you can, approve and then paste the approved scan link in an update to your question.